# Backing up registry using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, registry

I have windows 7 ultimate 32 bit and and I need a batch script that can backup the registry to a .reg file call "Registry backup" in the same directory as the batch file can any one help me find a code to do this.

Comment: I was receiving error 1282. I changed Rhak's script "%errorlevel%"=="1" to %errorlevel%"=="0", rearranged commands and added errorlevel to the failed message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exporting the whole registry to a single .reg file is not so easy, but you *can* use the `Reg.exe` utility that is installed with Windows to export a chosen root key.

Documentation for `Reg.exe` [can be found here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx).

For example, to save each of the valid root keys (and all sub-keys) to their own files, you could do this:

```
ECHO OFF
reg export HKLM hklm.reg > nul
reg export HKCU hkcu.reg > nul
reg export HKCR hkcr.reg > nul
reg export HKU  hku.reg > nul
reg export HKCC hkcc.reg > nul
```

There is also a [`save` option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742108.aspx), that does a similar thing but stores the data in a different format.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify *Mr. Roger Rowland's answer*, we may execute this syntax within CMD.

```
C:\Users\MrCMD>FOR %K IN (LM CU CR U CC) DO @REG.EXE EXPORT HK%K hk%K.reg [enter]
```

Or do those more informative within Batch Script, we may named it "**BUpRegWin.CMD**"

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%k in (lm cu cr u cc) do call :ExpReg %%k
goto :eof
:ExpReg
reg.exe export hk%1 hk%1.reg > nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (
  echo ^>^> Export --hk%1-- Failed.
) else (
  echo ^>^> Export --hk%1-- Fine.
)
goto :eof
endlocal
```

Brighter ideas are welcome. Feel free to improve. Thank you in advanced. :) :) :)