# Export registry

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I based my attempt off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655673/backing-up-registry-using-batch) post, using

```
    reg export HKLM hklm.reg > nul
    reg export HKCU hkcu.reg > nul
    reg export HKCR hkcr.reg > nul
    reg export HKU  hku.reg > nul
    reg export HKCC hkcc.reg > nul
```

and then attempted to copy them together using

```
    copy hklm.reg+hkcu.reg+hkcr.reg+hku.reg+hkcc.reg
```

This appears to work fine, however I notice it is a different size than a normal registry export. Can anyone give me any insight to why that is before I start looking for differences. Or, is there another way to take a registry export from the command line? I could use javascript/vbs/powershell if they were required for it, but I'm trying to limit the amount of files this script needs.

Comment: Using __copy__ for concatenation of ASCII files results in appending EOF character. Insert after __copy__ the option `/B`. BTW: `regedit.exe /a /e EntireRegistry.reg` exports entire registry in *REGEDIT4* format (ASCII/ANSI) and without `/a` in *Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00* format (Unicode). This makes also a huge difference in file size in comparison using command __reg__.

Comment: @Mofi that's a much more usable command, thank you so much. For some reason my searching didn't turn it up. 
You wouldn't happen to know how to use it on another computer on the domain, would you? I've got the start remote reg service included in the script, which I know needs to be done.

Comment: Try to run __regedit__ on remote computers of domain using [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).